# Crypto++ AES Decrypt how to?

Tags: cryptography, encryption, crypto++

There are next to no noob guides to crypto++ out there. Or none that I've found anyway. What I want to do is decrypt an array of uchars I generate with another AES encrypter. Where would I start? I have the library built and linking grand. Do I need to set anything up or do I just call a function on my array (and if so what function) ?

I'd really appreshiate some help from someone who knows this stuff.

Thanks

Comment: Experience has shown that the current state-of-the-art in crypto API's are dangerous for noobs to play with. Understanding them seems to require a lot of *crypto* knowledge which can't be learned in a quick getting started -type guide.

Comment: indigoOrange - keep in mind that encryption alone is rarely enough. You usually want an authenticated encryption mode. In the absence of other information, you nearly always prefer `EAX`, `GCM` or `CCM` modes over other modes like `CBC` mode. And you almost always avoid `ECB` mode like the plague because it looses semantic security when you reuse the encryption key or encrypt more than one block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't say I "know my stuff" too much about this, but here's some test code I put together to encrypt/decrypt strings with AES. Extending this to use some other data shouldn't be too hard.

```
string output;
CTR_Mode<AES>::Encryption encrypt((const byte*)key,AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH,(const byte*)iv);
StringSource(plaintext, true, new StreamTransformationFilter(encrypt, new StringSink(output)));
cout << "Encrypted: " << output << endl;

string res;
CTR_Mode<AES>::Decryption decrypt((const byte*)key,AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH,(const byte*)iv);
StringSource(output, true, new StreamTransformationFilter(decrypt, new StringSink(res)));
cout << "Decrypted: " << res << endl;
```

While working on this, I found the source code in the Crypto++ test program (the VisualStudio project called "cryptest") to be a big help. It was a little tough to read at first, but it gets easier as you work with it. I also got a lot of help understanding the available block cipher modes from Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of resources from a Google search:

http://www.bitvise.com/users-guide.html

http://andreyvit.livejournal.com/37576.html