# Decrypting using AES / Crypto++

Tags: c++, aes, crypto++

I'm trying to figure out how to decrypt a block of cipher text using AES. I am using the crypto++ library - or at least TRYING to use that library. But I'm getting absolutely nowhere. I assume that it is only a couple of lines of code to run this decryption algorithm, but I can't figure it out. This is what I have written. Start laughing now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <rijndael.h>
#include <sha.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    // Decryption
    CTR_Mode< AES >::Decryption decryptor;
    decryptor.SetKeyWithIV( cbcKey, AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH, cbcCipher );
}
```

Can anyone give me a brief tutorial on how to "simply" decrypt a 16-byte block of cipher text given a decryption key using crypto++? Their documentation is more cryptic than the cipher text you see above (at least for me), and I'm finding little help by searching.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Is your code even compiling without error?  Also, what is your build platform?

Comment: You don't seem to be using standard C(++). What kind of compiler (extension) are you using to allow the syntax you use to intialize the cbcKey and cbcCipher arrays?

Comment: Sorry about the code. I was just typing it to give an idea of what I'm trying to do. I changed the variable types to strings and showed how I think that they get referenced within the crypto++ lines. What I am looking for help with are those last two lines. They don't compile as written, and I have no idea how to correct them. For that matter, they are probably the entirely wrong lines of code to do what I want. I just put code on this post because people often get mad if you just ask for general help. Like asking for general help is somehow wrong...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Crypto++ AES Decrypt how to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131377/crypto-aes-decrypt-how-to)

Answer (score 1):

The FAQ at the crypto++ library webpage contains pointers to a "tutorial", go read it [over there](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/FAQ).

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone give me a brief tutorial on how to "simply" decrypt a 16-byte block of cipher text given a decryption key using crypto++?

This from the Crypto++ wiki. It provides a [CTR mode example](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/CTR_Mode).

```
AutoSeededRandomPool prng;

SecByteBlock key(AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
prng.GenerateBlock( key, key.size() );

byte ctr[ AES::BLOCKSIZE ];
prng.GenerateBlock( ctr, sizeof(ctr) );

string plain = "CTR Mode Test";
string cipher, encoded, recovered;

/*********************************\
\*********************************/

try
{
    cout << "plain text: " << plain << endl;

    CTR_Mode< AES >::Encryption e;
    e.SetKeyWithIV( key, key.size(), ctr );

    // The StreamTransformationFilter adds padding
    //  as required. ECB and CBC Mode must be padded
    //  to the block size of the cipher. CTR does not.
    StringSource ss1( plain, true, 
        new StreamTransformationFilter( e,
            new StringSink( cipher )
        ) // StreamTransformationFilter      
    ); // StringSource
}
catch( CryptoPP::Exception& e )
{
    cerr << e.what() << endl;
    exit(1);
}

/*********************************\
\*********************************/

// Pretty print cipher text
StringSource ss2( cipher, true,
    new HexEncoder(
        new StringSink( encoded )
    ) // HexEncoder
); // StringSource
cout << "cipher text: " << encoded << endl;

/*********************************\
\*********************************/

try
{
    CTR_Mode< AES >::Decryption d;
    d.SetKeyWithIV( key, key.size(), ctr );

    // The StreamTransformationFilter removes
    //  padding as required.
    StringSource ss3( cipher, true, 
        new StreamTransformationFilter( d,
            new StringSink( recovered )
        ) // StreamTransformationFilter
    ); // StringSource

    cout << "recovered text: " << recovered << endl;
}
catch( CryptoPP::Exception& e )
{
    cerr << e.what() << endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

Here's the result of running the sample program:

```
$ ./crytpopp-test.exe 
key: F534FC7F0565A8CF1629F01DB31AE3CA
counter: A4D16CBC010DACAA2E54FA676B57A345
plain text: CTR Mode Test
cipher text: 12455EDB41020E6D751F207EE6
recovered text: CTR Mode Test
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, Crypto++ tutorials a quite hard to follow. In general, in order to use Crypto++ API you need to have at least some basic knowledge about Cryptography, I would suggest [this Cryptography course](https://class.coursera.org/crypto-012).

Having said that, let me address your question. Since it is a little bit ambiguous, I would assume that you would like to decrypt an AES cipher, using CTR mode. As input, let's say you have a cipher, the IV and the key (all represented in hex in a `std::string`).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "crypto++/modes.h" // For CTR_Mode
#include "crypto++/filters.h" //For StringSource
#include "crypto++/aes.h" // For AES
#include "crypto++/hex.h" // For HexDecoder

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Our input:
    // Note: the input was previously generated by the same cipher 
    std::string iv_string = "37C6D22FADE22B2D924598BEE2455EFC";
    std::string cipher_string = "221DF9130F0E05E7E87C89EE6A";
    std::string key_string = "7D9BB722DA2DC8674E08C3D44AAE976F";

    std::cout << "Cipher text: " << cipher_string << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Key: " << key_string << std::endl;
    std::cout << "IV: " << iv_string << std::endl;

    // 1. Decode iv: 
    // At the moment our input is encoded in string format...
    // we need it in raw hex: 
    byte iv[CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE] = {};
    // this decoder would transform our std::string into raw hex:
    CryptoPP::HexDecoder decoder;
    decoder.Put((byte*)iv_string.data(), iv_string.size());
    decoder.MessageEnd();
    decoder.Get(iv, sizeof(iv));

    // 2. Decode cipher:
    // Next, we do a similar trick for cipher, only here we would leave raw hex
    //  in a std::string.data(), since it is convenient for us to pass this
    // std::string to the decryptor mechanism:
    std::string cipher_raw;
    {
        CryptoPP::HexDecoder decoder;
        decoder.Put((byte*)cipher_string.data(), cipher_string.size());
        decoder.MessageEnd();

        long long size = decoder.MaxRetrievable();
        cipher_raw.resize(size);       
        decoder.Get((byte*)cipher_raw.data(), cipher_raw.size());
        // If we print this string it's completely rubbish: 
        // std::cout << "Raw cipher: " << cipher_raw << std::endl;
    }

    // 3. Decode the key:
    // And finally the same for the key:
    byte key[CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH];
    {
        CryptoPP::HexDecoder decoder;
        decoder.Put((byte*)key_string.data(), key_string.size());
        decoder.MessageEnd();
        decoder.Get(key, sizeof(key));
    }

    // 4. Decrypt:
    std::string decrypted_text;
    try {
            CryptoPP::CTR_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Decryption d;
            d.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), iv);

            CryptoPP::StringSource ss(
                cipher_raw, 
                true, 
                new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter(
                    d,
                    new CryptoPP::StringSink(decrypted_text)
                ) // StreamTransformationFilter
            ); // StringSource

            std::cout << "Decrypted text: " << decrypted_text << std::endl;
    }
    catch( CryptoPP::Exception& e ) {
            std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
            exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it on Ubutunu 14.04, using Crypto++562:

`g++ -Wall -std=c++0x -o prog practicalAES.cpp -lcryptopp`

If I run the program, I get this output:

`Cipher text: 221DF9130F0E05E7E87C89EE6A
Key: 7D9BB722DA2DC8674E08C3D44AAE976F
IV: 37C6D22FADE22B2D924598BEE2455EFC
Decrypted text: CTR Mode Test`

It's not really visible here, but both the Key and the IV have the same length - 16 bytes (or 128 bits). This is the block size, so this cipher is AES-128. Since it is the CTR mode, no padding is added, and both the cipher and the plain text have the same number of bytes.

Also note that 60% of the code involves decoding the string into hex, while the decryption itself is only the last step (so if your input data comes as raw hex, no decoding is needed).

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial of Crypto++ is focused on the usage of filters and sources and sinks, which are, in my opinion, over complicated. In your case the code is actually very simple:

```
CTR_Mode< AES >::Decryption decryptor;
decryptor.SetKeyWithIV( cbcKey, AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH, cbcCipher );
decryptor.ProcessData(output, input, size);

// Decrypt another piece of data with the same key
decryptor.Resynchronize(new_iv, new_iv_length);
decryptor.ProcessData(new_output, new_input, size);
```